# How to zoom inner contents as per the parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Picture clearly describes that the inner contents is larger than than the parent container, so I want to use zoom technique so that the inner contents proportionally decrease to fit the parent container.

So, how could I implement?

---

I'm just talking about using zoom technique like this:

```
.inner-container{
zoom: .5;
-moz-transform: scale(.5);
}
```

But I'm stuck how can I calculate using jquery or javascript the zoom value should be set!

Comment: Well, you can use % height/width on the inner contents.

Comment: so, there is the problem what percent should I use as if the inner contents would be different, no?

Comment: This depents on the content of the inner element. You can resize an image for a zoom like effect, but when you have text content this will take a different approach

Comment: I'm not talking for image and for the contents any type. But div should be zoomed so this fit to the parent..

Comment: You should use the percent that fits your needs. If you explain better what kind of contents you have, we can help you better. Like Nico O said, text content act differently on resize.

Comment: any html elements but what exact percent would you use if the inner contents width height may vary...

Comment: Here is an example of the "issue" http://jsfiddle.net/rG7BF/ with different content types

Comment: There isn't a specific answer to what you're asking. I repeat... It depends. If you need an image that fits half the size of its parent you should use 50%. But this is a specific case.

Comment: I just want to transform the contents to fit the contents inside the parent div... check my updates...

Comment: There're many ways. You can use percent on height/width or `max-height`/`max-width` on the inner element so it doesn't overflow its parent.

Comment: I don't want like that but contents in zoomed state...

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/8JAUA/17/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="inner-content">
      .....
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".parent").each(function(){

    // get parent height you intend to show
    var p   = $(this).css("padding").replace("px","");
    var h   = $(this).css("height").replace("px","");
    var ph  = h-2*p; 

    // get inner height
    var $ic = $(this).find(".inner-content");
    var ih  = $ic.height();

    // set zoom size
    $ic.css('zoom',ph/ih);

    $(this).height(ph);

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually you understand what i wanted to do but this ratio only height i want both height and width ratio